# Django block trans count plural

Tags: django, templates

Is it normal that when the value 0 is returned we get plural ?
For example:

```
{% blocktrans count 0 as number %}
    {{number}} ticket created
{% plural %}
     {{number}} tickets created
{% endblocktrans %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the language, 0 in English is plural.